# Can someone help me understanding this code please?

Tags: python, function, math

```
def fibonacci(n):
    if 0 <= n <= 1:
        return n

    n_minus1, n_minus2 = 1, 0
    result = None
    for f in range(n - 1):
       result = n_minus2 + n_minus1
       n_minus2 = n_minus1
       n_minus1 = result

    return result
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Where exactly do you struggle to understand the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for asking the questions.
This code is for basically for adding the series of fibonacci series.Taking n or number of element of series are argument.

```
def fibonacci(n):
    if 0 <= n <= 1:
        return n
    n_minus1, n_minus2 = 1, 0
    result = None
    for f in range(n - 1):
        result = n_minus2 + n_minus1
        n_minus2 = n_minus1
        n_minus1 = result
    return result
print(fibonacci(1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using a couple of different numbers for `n` and see what results you get. You should be getting [Fibonacci numbers](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number).